# Error installing idb iOS pen testing tool on Mac

Tags: ios, ruby, rubygems, indexeddb, cydia

```
Fetching libxml-ruby-3.1.0.gem
Fetching mini_portile2-2.4.0.gem
Fetching nokogiri-1.10.10.gem
Building native extensions. This could take a while...
Successfully installed sqlite3-1.4.2
Building native extensions. This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing idb:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    current directory: /Users/dhruvbaviskar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/qtbindings-4.8.6.5
/Users/dhruvbaviskar/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.1/bin/ruby -I /Users/dhruvbaviskar/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.4.0 -r ./siteconf20210417-63256-bumwrc.rb extconf.rb

current directory: /Users/dhruvbaviskar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/qtbindings-4.8.6.5
make DESTDIR\= clean
mkdir ext/build
mkdir bin/2.4
mkdir bin/plugins
mkdir bin/plugins/accessible
mkdir bin/plugins/bearer
mkdir bin/plugins/codecs
mkdir bin/plugins/designer
mkdir bin/plugins/graphicssystems
mkdir bin/plugins/iconengines
mkdir bin/plugins/imageformats
mkdir bin/plugins/phonon_backend
mkdir bin/plugins/qmltooling
mkdir bin/plugins/sqldrivers
mkdir lib/2.4
cd ext/build; rm -rf CMakeFiles
cd ext/build; rm -rf generator
cd ext/build; rm -rf smoke
cd ext/build; rm -rf ruby
cd ext/build; rm *
rm: *: No such file or directory
make: [clean] Error 1 (ignored)

current directory: /Users/dhruvbaviskar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/qtbindings-4.8.6.5
make DESTDIR\=
mkdir ext/build
mkdir: ext/build: File exists
make: [makedirs] Error 1 (ignored)
mkdir bin/2.4
mkdir: bin/2.4: File exists
make: [makedirs] Error 1 (ignored)
mkdir bin/plugins
mkdir: bin/plugins: File exists
make: [makedirs] Error 1 (ignored)
mkdir bin/plugins/accessible
mkdir: bin/plugins/accessible: File exists
make: [makedirs] Error 1 (ignored)
mkdir bin/plugins/bearer
mkdir: bin/plugins/bearer: File exists
make: [makedirs] Error 1 (ignored)
mkdir bin/plugins/codecs
mkdir: bin/plugins/codecs: File exists
make: [makedirs] Error 1 (ignored)
mkdir bin/plugins/designer
mkdir: bin/plugins/designer: File exists
make: [makedirs] Error 1 (ignored)
mkdir bin/plugins/graphicssystems
mkdir: bin/plugins/graphicssystems: File exists
make: [makedirs] Error 1 (ignored)
mkdir bin/plugins/iconengines
mkdir: bin/plugins/iconengines: File exists
make: [makedirs] Error 1 (ignored)
mkdir bin/plugins/imageformats
mkdir: bin/plugins/imageformats: File exists
make: [makedirs] Error 1 (ignored)
mkdir bin/plugins/phonon_backend
mkdir: bin/plugins/phonon_backend: File exists
make: [makedirs] Error 1 (ignored)
mkdir bin/plugins/qmltooling
mkdir: bin/plugins/qmltooling: File exists
make: [makedirs] Error 1 (ignored)
mkdir bin/plugins/sqldrivers
mkdir: bin/plugins/sqldrivers: File exists
make: [makedirs] Error 1 (ignored)
mkdir lib/2.4
mkdir: lib/2.4: File exists
make: [makedirs] Error 1 (ignored)
cd ext/build; rm -rf CMakeFiles
cd ext/build; rm -rf generator
cd ext/build; rm -rf smoke
cd ext/build; rm -rf ruby
cd ext/build; rm *
rm: *: No such file or directory
make: [clean] Error 1 (ignored)
cd ext/build; \
cmake -DCMAKE_MINIMUM_REQUIRED_VERSION=2.6 \
-G "Unix Makefiles" \
-Wno-dev \
-DRUBY_EXECUTABLE=/Users/dhruvbaviskar/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.1/bin/ruby \
..
-- The C compiler identification is AppleClang 12.0.0.12000032
-- The CXX compiler identification is AppleClang 12.0.0.12000032
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working C compiler: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/cc - skipped
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/c++ - skipped
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
CMake Error at /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/3.20.1/share/cmake/Modules/FindQt4.cmake:1314 (message):
  Found unsuitable Qt version "6.0.3" from /usr/local/bin/qmake, this code
  requires Qt 4.x
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  generator/CMakeLists.txt:3 (find_package)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/Users/dhruvbaviskar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/qtbindings-4.8.6.5/ext/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "/Users/dhruvbaviskar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/qtbindings-4.8.6.5/ext/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
make: [build] Error 1 (ignored)
cd ext/build; make
make[1]: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.
make: *** [build] Error 2

make failed, exit code 2

Gem files will remain installed in /Users/dhruvbaviskar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/qtbindings-4.8.6.5 for inspection.
Results logged to /Users/dhruvbaviskar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/extensions/x86_64-darwin-20/2.4.0/qtbindings-4.8.6.5/gem_make.out
```

Answer (score 0):

The important part of the error message is:

> Found unsuitable Qt version "6.0.3" from /usr/local/bin/qmake, this code requires Qt 4.x

You appear to have QT 6.0.3 installed (potentially via Homebrew). The `qtbindings`  gem you are trying to install there (likely as a transient dependency) requires QT 4 however.

With homebrew, you could install it with

```sh
brew tap cartr/qt4
brew install qt@4
```